# I cant' change my folders icons [17.04]

Tags: unity, icons, themes, directory, desktop-background

After changing the wallpaper for one I downloaded, I lost my custom icons. Not the icon theme, but the icons I've put through right click → *Properties*.
I've already tried to change back to a default wallpaper, but it doesn't seems to help.
My icons are in folder Pictures/Icons, and yes, I changed this location a lot of times, but it didn't work. Now it looks like this,

[image]

with my `.sh` file without icon and two folders in plank without icons too.

Comment: Hi, Gabriel.  That's not associated to wallpaper, but to icon themes. Do you installed Numix or Papirus? It seems this icon theme doesn't support folders icon customization. Try to revert to former icon theme you have used before, to be sure of it.

Comment: @Redbob Yes, I'm using Papirus, however, I have used it  for a long time, even after the modifications to the icons were made. And I've also changed the icon theme to the default ubuntu-mono-dark, but nothing changes after the reboot.